# loop over files with bash script

Tags: bash, loops, type-conversion, kml

I have a [js script](https://github.com/nerik/google-timeline-to-csv) that converts kml location history files to csv. I wrote a bash script to loop through all the files in a directory. The script works when I execute it from command line `./index.js filename.kml > filename.csv`

But nothing happens when I execute the bash file that is supposed to loop through all files.

I know it probably is a simple mistake but I can't spot it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo.sh
for f in *.kml; do
  test -e "${f%.kml}" && continue
  ./index.js "$f" > "-fcsv"
done
```

Comment: What is the test supposed to test? Can 'f in *.kml' return files, which don't exist? Why do you want to skip existing files? Cargo-cult-programming?

Comment: Cargo-cult-programming wow LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the "&& continue", if I'm not wrong you're skipping the current iteration with the "continue" keyword, that's why nothing happens

EDIT

<s>Also, you shouldn't test if the file exists, the for loop is enough to be sure that "f" will be a valid .kml file. Anyways, if you still want to do it you have to do it like:</s>

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo.sh
for f in *.kml; do
  if [ -e "$f" ]; then
  ./index.js "$f" > "$f.csv"
  fi;
done
```

Comment: No, if there are no `*.kml` files the loop will be run on the raw unexpanded wildcard. Checking that the wildcard actually matched something is a common and useful idiom. (The OP clearly attempted to apply it incorrectly, though, whereas this code is *almost* correct. Failing to quote the variable in the `if` is a common beginner error. You might want to check http://shellcheck.net/ to diagnose simple errors like this.)

Comment: ... And I guess the output redirection should probably be `>"${f%.kml}.csv"`

Comment: The purpose of the line is to only convert files that have not been converted yet.

Comment: Lesson reinforced: Code which doesn't do what you want is a *terrible* way to try to explain what you do want.